# How can I fix this error in python 3.8 pycharm? It is about importing packages

Tags: python, keras, pycharm, macos-sierra

This is the error it gives me when I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kids/Library/Mail/V5/E60CBF1C-9021-4A10-8D60-06C96C141AF1/Outbox.mbox/E7C72E99-E3DB-4CDC-B1C9-15116F3478D8/Data/Attachments/405/2/ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition-master/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D, MaxPooling3D
```

This is the code error which it is showing:

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D, MaxPooling3D
```

Keras version is 2.3.1. Python version is Python 3.8. Running on MacOS.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment? Python version, version of keras package etc.? You also seem to be missing the actual error - please provide the full trace back.

Comment: Keras version is 2.3.1. Python version is Python 3.8

Comment: The trace back error is Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It looks as though those imports exist in `keras.layers`, rather than `keras.layers.convolutional`. From the [pooling docs](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/) and [convolutional docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/). This can also be seen in the [source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/__init__.py). Certainly `MaxPooling3D` cannot be imported from the `convolutional` module.

Comment: Note that your trace back still doesn't indicate what the actual problem is, there is no error message shown.

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: A stack trace should usually include an exception, which indicates what the error actually is. From what you have shown, we don't know what occurred when python tried to execute that line. If there is no more information, can you try my proposed solution?

Comment: Yes, the traceback is incomplete, so we do not know what the problem is in this question.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kids/Library/Mail/V5/E60CBF1C-9021-4A10-8D60-06C96C141AF1/Outbox.mbox/E7C72E99-E3DB-4CDC-B1C9-15116F3478D8/Data/Attachments/405/2/ASL-Finger-Spelling-Recognition-master/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D`

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: No... please provide every line output as part of that traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D, MaxPooling3D
```

attempts to import `MaxPooling3D` from `keras.layers.convolutional`. `MaxPooling3D` is actually part of the `pooling` module, i.e. `keras.layers.pooling`.

According to the keras [source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/__init__.py) and [docs](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/), the best way to import these two classes in a single statement would be

```
from keras.layers import Convolution3D, MaxPooling3D
```

Alternatively, you could import them separately:

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling3D
```

but in general, you should pay attention to what is purposefully exposed via the package; that is, the classes accessible from `keras.layers`.